# undefined reference to `ros::init(int&, char**, std::string const&, unsigned int)'

Tags: ros, rviz, ros-jade

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I was trying to build ros package but while doing catkin_make, I am getting error

```
undefined reference to `ros::init(int&, char**, std::string const&, unsigned int)'
```

I followed the tutorial exactly as mentioned on [Markers: Sending Basic Shapes (C++)](http://wiki.ros.org/rviz/Tutorials/Markers%3A%20Basic%20Shapes) but still I am not able to build the package. I looked up online but most of forums state the problems which is not present with my code.

While creating package I used command:

```
catkin_create_pkg using_markers roscpp visualization_msgs
```

I have added `target_link_libraries(basic_shapes ${catkin_LIBRARIES})` in `CMakeLists.txt` as well. In spite of that, I am getting undefined reference.

Note: I am using Jade distribution of ROS.

Edit:
Content of CMakeLists.txt:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8.3)
project(using_markers)

add_executable(basic_shapes src/basic_shapes.cpp)
target_link_libraries(basic_shapes ${catkin_LIBRARIES})

## Find catkin macros and libraries
## if COMPONENTS list like find_package(catkin REQUIRED COMPONENTS xyz)
## is used, also find other catkin packages
find_package(catkin REQUIRED COMPONENTS
  roscpp
  visualization_msgs
)

###################################
## catkin specific configuration ##
###################################
## The catkin_package macro generates cmake config files for your package
## Declare things to be passed to dependent projects
## INCLUDE_DIRS: uncomment this if you package contains header files
## LIBRARIES: libraries you create in this project that dependent projects also need
## CATKIN_DEPENDS: catkin_packages dependent projects also need
## DEPENDS: system dependencies of this project that dependent projects also need
catkin_package(
#  INCLUDE_DIRS include
#  LIBRARIES using_markers
#  CATKIN_DEPENDS roscpp visualization_msgs
#  DEPENDS system_lib
)

###########
## Build ##
###########

## Specify additional locations of header files
## Your package locations should be listed before other locations
# include_directories(include)
include_directories(
  ${catkin_INCLUDE_DIRS}
)
```

Any insight in this regard will be helpful.

Thanks.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/220579/undefined-reference-to-%60ros::init(int&,-char**,-std::string-const&,-unsigned-int)%27/) by [cybodroid](https://answers.ros.org/users/25023/cybodroid/) on ROS Answers with karma: 234 on 2015-11-07

Post score: 4

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Akif](https://answers.ros.org/users/23527/akif/) on 2015-11-07**:
It would be helpful if you can post your CMakeLists.txt file content.

**Comment by [cybodroid](https://answers.ros.org/users/25023/cybodroid/) on 2015-11-07**:
I have edited question details and added the content of CMakeLists.txt

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Your CMakeLists is not in the correct order; you define your executable and add libraries before you indicate which libraries to link to; this results in not linking to any libraries. (unfortunately, cmake does not warn you if you use a variable before it is defined).

You should reorder you cmakelists so that the calls to `find_package(catkin ...)`, `catkin_package(...)` and `include_directories()` come **before** any calls to `add_executable()`, `add_library()` or `target_link_libraries()`.

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2015-11-07

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 8

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [cybodroid](https://answers.ros.org/users/25023/cybodroid/) on 2015-11-07**:
Hey. Thanks for the help. You pointed out rightly and it worked.